# Mouse Detection in a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, position, cursor, dropdown

So I have a windows form with a drop down in it. I want to check if the cursor is on a ComboBox control. This works with the code

```
if(Combobox1.Bounds.Contains(PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
{
   //Do some stuff here
}
```

However when I select the combobox drop down and move the mouse over the dropped menu the above method no longer works.
Anyway to detect this, thanks?

Comment: Winform / WPF/ ??

Comment: it's a winform.

Comment: Something like this?? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14255/ComboBox-firing-events-when-hovering-on-the-dropdo

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late, but it may help someone viewing this.

You need to double check the rest of your code, because you probably changed your "comboBox.AllowDrop" to false in a block that you didn't stated in your question.

It should appear as follows:

```
comboBox1.AllowDrop = false;
```